# Ceaser Cipher crack using C language

Tags: c, encryption, brute-force

I am writing a program to decrypt text using ceaser cypher algorithm.
till now my code is working fine and gets all possible decrypted results but I have to show just the correct one, how can I do this?
below is the code to get all decrypted strings.
for my code answer should be "3 hello world".

```
void main(void)
{
  char input[] = "gourz#roohk";
  for(int key = 1;x<26;key++)
  {
    printf("%i",input[I]-x%26);
    for(int i = strlen(input)-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
      printf("%c",input[I]-x%26);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your expected input and output?

Comment: my input is initialized in char input[], assume it as encypted text, and my result should be "3 hello world "

Comment: I am searching it from yesterday and yes I am not able to convey properly that what exactly I want,

Comment: from my search I found that brute force and frequency analysis can d the trick but I can't understand how frequency analysis can work for my situation.

Comment: Note: `input[I]-x%26` is the same as `input[I]-(x%26)`  Did you want `(input[I]-x)%26`?

Comment: I want ((input[I]-x)%26)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place and you can format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a Caesar Cipher has only 25 possible shifts. Also, for text of non-trivial length, it's *highly* likely that **only** one shift will make the input make sense. One possible approach, then, is to see if the result of the shift makes sense; if it does, then it's probably the correct shift (e.g. compare words against a dictionary to see if they're "real" words; not sure if you've done web services yet, but there are [free dictionary APIs](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-free-to-use-dictionary-API) available).

Consider the following text: `3 uryyb jbeyq`. Some possible shifts of this:

- 3 gdkkn vnqkc (12)
- 3 xubbe mehbt (3)
- 3 hello world (13)
- 3 jgnnq yqtnf (15)
- Etc.

As you can see, only the shift of 13 makes this text contain "real" words, so the correct shift is probably 13.

Another possible solution (albeit more complicated) is through [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) (i.e. see if the resulting text has the same - or similar - statistical characteristics as English). For example, in English the most frequent letter is "e," so the correct shift will likely have "e" as the most frequent letter. By way of example, the first paragraph of this answer contains 48 instances of the letter "e", but if you shift it by 15 letters, it only has 8:

> Gtrpaa iwpi p Rpthpg Rxewtg wph dcan 25 edhhxqat hwxuih. Pahd, udg
>   itmi du cdc-igxkxpa atcviw, xi'h wxvwan axztan iwpi dcan dct hwxui
>   lxaa bpzt iwt xceji bpzt htcht. Dct edhhxqat peegdprw, iwtc, xh id htt
>   xu iwt gthjai du iwt hwxui bpzth htcht; xu xi sdth, iwtc xi'h egdqpqan
>   iwt rdggtri hwxui (t.v. rdbepgt ldgsh pvpxchi p sxrixdcpgn id htt xu
>   iwtn'gt "gtpa" ldgsh; cdi hjgt xu ndj'kt sdct ltq htgkxrth nti, qji
>   iwtgt pgt ugtt sxrixdcpgn PEXh pkpxapqat).

The key word here is "likely" - it's not at all statistically certain (especially for shorter texts) and it's possible to write text that's resistant to that technique to some degree (e.g. through deliberate misspellings, [lipograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipogram), etc.). Note that I actually have an example of an exception above - "3 xubbe mehbt" has more instances of the letter "e" than "3 hello world" even though the second one is clearly the correct shift - so you probably want to apply several statistical tests to increase your confidence (especially for shorter texts).

Answer (score 0):

Hello to make an attack on caesar cipher more speed  way is the frequency analysis attack where you count the frequency of each letter in your text and how many times it appeared and compare this letter to the most appearing  letters in English  in this link 
 ( https://www3.nd.edu/~busiforc/handouts/cryptography/letterfrequencies.html ) 
then by applying this table to the letters you can git the text   or use this link its a code on get hub (https://github.com/tombusby/understanding-cryptography-exercises/blob/master/Chapter-01/ex1.2.py) 
in python for letter frequency   last resort answer is the brute force because its more complexity  compared to  the frequency analysis
brute  force here is 26!  which means by getting a letter the space of search of letters decrease by one

if you want to use your code you can make a file   for the most  popular strings in english  and every time you decrypt you search in this file but this is high cost of time   to do so letter frequency is more better